# How to call functions by their pointers passing multiple arguments in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I need to make a "function caller" function: it receives a generic function pointer  (`void *`) and a variable number of arguments as arguments and it's got to call this function, passing the arguments, and return a generic pointer to the returning value. However, this entry-function pointer may point to any kind of function (with any returning type), even to functions with a constant number of arguments. It would be something like:

```
void * function_caller(void * function_pointer, ...) {
  void * returning_value;

  // Call the function and get the returning value

  return returning_value;   // this returning value will be properly casted outside
}
```

This way, the following code would work:

```
int function1(int a, char b) {
  // ...
}

void function2(float c) {
  // ...
}

float function3() {
  // ...
}

int main() {
  int v1;
  float v3;

  v1 = *(int *) function_caller((void *) &function1, 10, 'a');  // Which would be equivalent to v1 = function1(10, 'a');
  function_caller((void *) &function2, 3.0);    // Which would be equivalent to function2(3.0);
  v3 = *(float *) function_caller((void *) &function3); // Which would be equivalent to v3 = function3();

  return 0;
}
```

I know I'll have to use a `va_list`, but I don't know how to call the function by a pointer  passing the arguments.

So, guys, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bad news is, this is not possible in C, even in unportable C.  (GCC has extensions which *sound like* they do this job, but they do not work in the general case.)  It is necessary to write assembly-language shims.

The good news is, other people have already written the shims for you: have a look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).  ([Manual here](http://www.manpagez.com/info/libffi/libffi-3.0.11/libffi_3.php#The-Basics).  Do not use the "closure" API if you can possibly avoid it.)

Comment: Aside from this, what the questioner wants isn't necessarily possible for a second reason, which is that `function_caller` takes varags. So for example the vararg `3.0` is passed as a double (and would be even if it was `3.0f`), and the type of the first argument has stripped the parameter types of `function2`. Therefore even once you play your assembler tricks, the only way you could possibly determine that the parameter should be passed as a `float` rather than a `double` is by examining `function2` itself to see whether *it* expects a `float` or a `double`. Which seems a bit implausible.

Comment: Libffi sounds quite interesting :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Your observation is quite justifiable, but in my application (as I haven't explained), functions are identified by their pointers and by encoding-strings which store returning and argument types. So, there is a arguments checking before the function calling. The example above is only an approximation of what I need to do, so things aren't going to work exactly that way.