# call a vararg function with an array?

Tags: c, arrays

In this example below, I would like to pass to a function that receive variable number of arguments the content of an array.

In other terms, I would like to pass to `printf` the content of `foo` by value and thus, pass these arguments on the stack.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int foo[] = {1,2,3,4};

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", foo);
}
```

I know this example looks stupid because I can use `printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", 1,2,3,4);`. Just imagine I'm calling `void bar(char** a, ...)` instead and the array is something I receive from RS232...

**EDIT**

In other words, I would like to avoid this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int foo[] = {1,2,3,4};

    switch(sizeof(foo))
    {
       case 1: printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", foo[0]); break;
       case 2: printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", foo[0], foo[1]); break;
       case 3: printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]); break;
       case 4: printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]); break;
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not possible. If you have an array then you need to call a function which can handle a passed array. In the case of your simple example, you have to create a wrapper function which takes the array as argument and loops over the array and in turn calls `printf`.

Comment: The size of an array is only known if it has been created statically! If you want to pass an array to a function, you have to define a tail element or pass the number of elements to the function as well.

Comment: Create [your own printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647278/minimal-fast-implementation-of-sprintf-for-embedded). While processing you will understand where problem with this question!

Comment: Just print the numbers one by one, in a loop. End of story.

Comment: In fact I am not using printf but another function that takes a variable number of arguments. I receive my arguments from a command line interface. These arguments are stored into an array and I have to pass these values to my function

Comment: I have a feeling this is an XY problem.  Perhaps showing us a more concrete example would help.  It's possible that the approach this function is taking to process its arguments can be optimized.

Comment: What is wrong with StackOverflow? Why has nobody mentioned `vprintf` yet?

Comment: `vprintf` won't help here.  But dbush is right about it being a sort of an XY problem.  The real question isn't about arrays or printf; it's the "inverse varargs" problem.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you cannot pass an array by value in a `va_arg` directly. It is possible though if it is packed inside a `struct`. It is not portable but one can do some things when the implementation is known.

Here an example, that might help.

```
void call(size_t siz, ...);

struct xx1 { int arr[1]; };
struct xx10 { int arr[10]; };
struct xx20 { int arr[20]; };

void call(size_t siz, ...)
{
  va_list va;
  va_start(va, siz);

  struct xx20 x = va_arg(va, struct xx20);
  printf("HEXDUMP:%s\n", HEXDUMP(&x, siz));
  va_end(va);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct xx10 aa = { {1,2,3,4,5,[9]=-1}};
  struct xx20 bb = { {[10]=1,2,3,4,5,[19]=-1}};
  struct xx1  cc = { {-1}};

  call(sizeof aa, aa);
  call(sizeof bb, bb);
  call(sizeof cc, cc);
 }
```

Will print following (`HEXDUMP()` is one of my debug functions, it's obvious what it does).

```
HEXDUMP:
  0x7fff1f154160:01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f154170:05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f154180:00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff                         ........

HEXDUMP:
  0x7fff1f154160:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f154170:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f154180:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f154190:03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  0x7fff1f1541a0:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ................
```

Tested on Linux x86_64 compiled with gcc 5.1 and Solaris SPARC9 compiled with gcc 3.4

I don't know if it is helpful, but it's maybe a start. As can be seen, using the biggest struct array in the functions `va_arg` allows to handle smaller arrays if the size is known. 
But be careful, it probably is full of undefined behaviours (example, if you call the function with a struct array size smaller than 4 int, it doesn't work on Linux x86_64 because the struct is passed by registers, not as an array on stack, but on your embedded processor it might work).

Comment: I dislike this solution. It works only with *static* arrays, not dynamically allocated ones. It needs to introduce a new stack type for each combination of array type and size. Its syntax is surprising. It still passes the size seperately, only to get the "benefits" of passing the array by value and vararg -- neither of which is a good idea really.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to pass to printf the content of foo by value and thus, pass these arguments on the stack.

You cannot pass an array by value. Not by "normal" function call, and not by varargs either (which is, basically, just a different way of **reading** the stack).

Whenever you use an array as argument to a function, what the called function *receives* is a pointer.

The easiest example for this is the char array, a.k.a. "string".

```
int main()
{
    char buffer1[100];
    char buffer2[] = "Hello";
    strcpy( buffer2, buffer1 );
}
```

What `strcpy()` "sees" is not two arrays, but two pointers:

```
char * strcpy( char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2 )
{
    // Yes I know this is a naive implementation in more than one way.
    char * rc = s1;
    while ( ( *s1++ = *s2++ ) );
    return rc;
}
```

(This is why the *size* of the array is only known in the scope the array was *declared* in. Once you pass it around, it's just a pointer, with no place to put the size information.)

The same holds true for passing an array to a varargs function: What ends up on the stack is a *pointer* to the (first element of) the array, not the whole array.

**You *can* pass an array by reference *and do useful things with it* in the called function if:**

1. you pass the (pointer to the) array *and a count of elements* (think `argc` / `argv`), or
2. caller and callee agree on a fixed size, or
3. caller and callee agree on the array being "terminated" in some way.

**Standard `printf()`** does the last one for `"%s"` and strings (which are terminated by `'\0'`), but **is not equipped to do so with, as in your example, an `int[]` array. So you would have to write your own custom `printme()`.**

In no case are you passing the array "by value". If you think about it, it wouldn't make much sense to copy all elements to the stack for larger arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't do it, it's impossible.

Slightly longer answer: Well, maybe you can do it, but it's super tricky.  You are basically trying to call a function with an argument list that is not known until run time.  There are libraries that can help you dynamically construct argument lists and call functions with them; one library is libffi: https://sourceware.org/libffi/.

See also question 15.13 in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) list: [How can I call a function with an argument list built up at run time?](http://c-faq.com/varargs/invvarargs.html)

See also these previous Stackoverflow questions:
[C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868/c-late-binding-with-unknown-arguments)
[How to call functions by their pointers passing multiple arguments in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206865/how-to-call-functions-by-their-pointers-passing-multiple-arguments-in-c)
[Calling a variadic function with an unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093317/calling-a-variadic-function-with-an-unknown-number-of-parameters/35093584)

Comment: [**Provide context for links**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: why was C made with such a stupid restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok look at this example, from my code. This is simple one way.

```
void my_printf(char const * frmt, ...)
{
    va_list argl;
    unsigned char const * tmp;
    unsigned char chr;
    va_start(argl,frmt);
    while ((chr = (unsigned char)*frmt) != (char)0x0) {
        frmt += 1;
        if (chr != '%') {
            dbg_chr(chr);
            continue;
        }
        chr = (unsigned char)*frmt;
        frmt += 1;
        switch (chr) {
        ...
        case 'S':
            tmp = va_arg(argl,unsigned char const *);
            dbg_buf_str(tmp,(uint16_t)va_arg(argl,int));
            break;
        case 'H':
            tmp = va_arg(argl,unsigned char const *);
            dbg_buf_hex(tmp,(uint16_t)va_arg(argl,int));
            break;
        case '%':   dbg_chr('%');   break;
        }
    }
    va_end(argl);
}
```

There dbg_chr(uint8_t byte) drop byte to USART and enable transmitter.

Use example:

```
#define TEST_LEN   0x4
uint8_t test_buf[TEST_LEN] = {'A','B','C','D'};
my_printf("This is hex buf: \"%H\"",test_buf,TEST_LEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, variadic argument might be passed as a struct-packed array:

```
void logger(char * bufr, uint32_t * args, uint32_t argNum) {
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);
    struct {
     uint32_t ar[16];
    } argStr;
    
        for(uint8_t a = 0; a < argNum; a += 1)
        argStr.ar[a] = args[a];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, bufr, argStr);
        strcat(buf, '\0');
        pushStr(buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

tested and works with gnu C compiler